# SQL: Create Customized Column Variable In SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to look for better way to store customized column (that called many times in queries) in SQL variable.

I’m using Oracle and I execute this query:

```
SELECT project, 
( CASE 
WHEN TO_CHAR((100 - round(value, 5) * 100)) NOT LIKE ‘.%’ 
THEN (100 - round(value, 5) * 100) || ‘%’ 
ELSE ‘0’ || (100 - round(value, 5) * 100) || ‘%’ 
END ) AS percentage 
FROM table;
```

> The customized column: `100 - round(value, 5)` is called 3 times. In addition, That customized column called in many other SELECT queries in my project. Is there any option to save that customized column as a variable and call it in shorter way?

For example, I would like to do something like that:

```
SELECT project, 
( CASE 
WHEN TO_CHAR(CUSTOMIZED_VALUE) NOT LIKE ‘.%’ 
THEN CUSTOMIZED_VALUE || ‘%’ 
ELSE ‘0’ || CUSTOMIZED_VALUE || ‘%’ 
END ) AS percentage 
FROM table;
```

Table Columns:

```
|  Column  |     Type    |
|:—————————|————————————:|
| project  |VARCHAR2(100)|
|  value   |  FLOAT(*)   |
```

When `value` is always between 0 to 1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share your table definition and some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a virtual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD customized_value NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (100 - round(value, 5) * 100);
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 0.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0.42 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1.00 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after you have added the column, when you query the table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

The output is:

| VALUE | CUSTOMIZED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| .42 | 58 |
| 1 | 0 |

And you can use `CUSTOMIZED_VALUE` in other, more complicated, expressions.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7HuH-UcO)

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in a sub-query (or a sub-query factoring clause) and then use it in an outer query:

```sql
SELECT project, 
       TO_CHAR(CUSTOMIZED_VALUE, 'FM990') || '%' AS percentage 
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         100 - round(value, 5) * 100 AS customized_value
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

or:

```sql
WITH subquery_factoring_clause (project, value, customized_value) AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         100 - round(value, 5) * 100 AS customized_value
  FROM   table_name t
)
SELECT project, 
       TO_CHAR(CUSTOMIZED_VALUE, 'FM990') || '%' AS percentage 
FROM   subquery_factoring_clause;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (project, value) AS
SELECT 'a', 0.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 0.42 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 1.00 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PROJECT | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100% |
| b | 58% |
| c | 0% |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p-HaL9Ln)

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I need to display also the 3 digits after the dot (0.000). How should I do it? And is it possible to get 0.005% instead .005% if the customized_value is 0.05?

Comment: @NBS Just change the format mode from `FM990` to `FM990.000` or `FM990.999` if you want to display more decimal places (or use your `CASE` expression if you want to use an implicit number-to-string conversion using the default formatting).